# Semantic UI Dropdown can't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have tried to deal with this problem for 2 days, but I still can't get the JavaScript of Semantic UI to work. This is my all code. My jQuery is not very good. I have read a lot, but it doesn't work.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
        minimum-                      scale=0.5, maximum-scale=2.0, 
        user-scalable=yes" /> <!--自适应-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" charset="utf-8">
        <title>后台管理系统</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/semantic.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.address.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/semantic.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
        .diymenu{background-color: blue;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding-top:0px;}
        body{margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;font-family: 微软雅黑;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#drop').click(function(){
        $('#drop').dropdown('show');
        });
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body >

        <!--导航栏  -->
        <div class="ui  blue inverted menu">
        <a class="active item"><i class="home icon"></i>主页</a>
        <div class="right menu">
        <a class="item"><i class="mail  icon"></i>消息
        <div class="ui black circular   label">2</div></a>
        <a class="item"> 

        </a>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui dropdown item" id="drop">
        More <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
        <a class="item"><i class="edit icon"></i>编辑个人信息</a>
        <a class="item"><i class="globe icon"></i>选择语言</a>
        <a class="item"><i class="settings icon"></i>账户设置</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: _What_ is not working? You need to be more specific, and reconsider just pasting the neccessary code - or into a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) - so it's easy for us to evaluate and understand the issue.

Answer (score 6):

From the docs at http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage, you should initialize your dropdown with Javascript (no further jquery code required):

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/fd8qfyra/1/ i think there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

After researching through blogs, youtube and more I found the answer, implemented it and given me the collapsing dropdown functionality with Semantic UI

1. **Put the CSS and semantic.js link inside the header instead of the body**
2. **Give the select an ID**

3.**Initialize the ID with with dropdown only:**

`$('#gender-select').dropdown();`